# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter with java-11 (or corretto-11)?

Tags: java

I have a maven pom.xml file which has an option to deploy a site to an s3 bucket. Using java8 works fine, but trying to migrate to java-11 and getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
at com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString (Base64.java:39)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject (AmazonS3Client.java:1574)
at org.kuali.common.aws.s3.S3Utils.upload (S3Utils.java:92)
at org.kuali.maven.wagon.FileHandler.handleElement (FileHandler.java:33)
at org.kuali.maven.wagon.FileHandler.handleElement (FileHandler.java:26)
at org.kuali.common.threads.ListIteratorThread.run (ListIteratorThread.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

I am using corretto-11

```
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.6.10.1 (build 11.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.6.10.1 (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

I've found some other resources in stackoverflow discussing adding dependencies in my maven pom file, but none of them works for me.
Thank you

Comment: Could it be related to this:  
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1092

Comment: have a look here, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: I was following the fix BillNaylor, but still no luck. I spend a while trying the different dependencies in question 43574426, still nothing seems to work.

Comment: I wish that the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j worked for me dnault, but none did. I tried all the different dependencies listed and none of them works. I'm using maven.